# Does Smarthome action project support the mutual TLS (mTLS) for Intent fulfillment?

Tags: google-smart-home

The document of Smarthome action doesn't provide any information about implementing the mutual TLS (mTLS) for smarthome intent fulfillment but I did found that the Dialogflow action project is now supports it ([ref](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-mtls)). Just wondering if I can apply it in the same way. Does anyone ever try?

The reason I ask the question before trying it because I use the AWS API gateway as a fulfillment endpoint. To use the mTLS, it cost me to purchase a custom domain and certificate for it.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular TLS system client authenticates the connected server by checking the network certificate and validating through the public/private key pair. This is important to make sure the client (you) sends the information to correct destination (Google). In mTLS, the server also validates the client by checking the certificate as well. For our APIs this is not necessary, as we are already authenticating your calls through a Bearer Token.